# FFMPEG getting error - The filename or extension is too long

Tags: c#, cmd, ffmpeg

I am merging my images to video but getting error on cmd when running by c# process - The filename or extension is too long

```
ffmpeg -i Temp\Videos\Input_5c9b6d5821e7fa9adc1da560.mp4 -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\4_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\6_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\8_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\9_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\10_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\12_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\13_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\14_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\16_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\18_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\20_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\21_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\23_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\25_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\27_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\28_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\30_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\32_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\34_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\36_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\38_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\40_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\41_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\42_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\44_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\46_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\47_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\49_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\51_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\53_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\55_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\57_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\59_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\61_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\63_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\65_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\67_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\69_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\71_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\72_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\74_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\76_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\78_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\79_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\80_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\81_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\83_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\84_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\85_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\86_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\88_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\89_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\90_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\91_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\93_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\95_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\97_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\98_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\100_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\101_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\103_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\105_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\107_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\109_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\111_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\113_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\115_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\117_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\119_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\120_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\122_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\123_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\125_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\942_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\943_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\944_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\945_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\946_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\947_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\948_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\949_1.jpg -i Temp\FrameProcessing\02-28-2019_02-41-25-PM\950_1.jpg -filter_complex [0]scale='iw-mod(iw,2)':'ih-mod(ih,2)'[m0];[m0][1]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,4,4)'[m1];[m1][2]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,6,6)'[m2];[m2][3]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,8,8)'[m3];[m3][4]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,9,9)'[m4];[m4][5]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,10,10)'[m5];[m5][6]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,12,12)'[m6];[m6][7]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,13,13)'[m7];[m7][8]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,14,14)'[m8];[m8][9]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,16,16)'[m9];[m9][10]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,18,18)'[m10];[m10][11]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,20,20)'[m11];[m11][12]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,21,21)'[m12];[m12][13]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,23,23)'[m13];[m13][14]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,25,25)'[m14];[m14][15]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,27,27)'[m15];[m15][16]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,28,28)'[m16];[m16][17]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,30,30)'[m17];[m17][18]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,32,32)'[m18];[m18][19]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,34,34)'[m19];[m19][20]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,36,36)'[m20];[m20][21]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,38,38)'[m21];[m21][22]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,40,40)'[m22];[m22][23]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,41,41)'[m23];[m23][24]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,42,42)'[m24];[m24][25]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,44,44)'[m25];[m25][26]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,46,46)'[m26];[m26][27]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,47,47)'[m27];[m27][28]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,49,49)'[m28];[m28][29]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,51,51)'[m29];[m29][30]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,53,53)'[m30];[m30][31]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,55,55)'[m31];[m31][32]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,57,57)'[m32];[m32][33]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,59,59)'[m33];[m33][34]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,61,61)'[m34];[m34][35]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,63,63)'[m35];[m35][36]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,65,65)'[m36];[m36][37]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,67,67)'[m37];[m37][38]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,69,69)'[m38];[m38][39]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,71,71)'[m39];[m39][40]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,72,72)'[m40];[m40][41]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,74,74)'[m41];[m41][42]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,76,76)'[m42];[m42][43]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,78,78)'[m43];[m43][44]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,79,79)'[m44];[m44][45]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,80,80)'[m45];[m45][46]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,81,81)'[m46];[m46][47]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,83,83)'[m47];[m47][48]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,84,84)'[m48];[m48][49]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,85,85)'[m49];[m49][50]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,86,86)'[m50];[m50][51]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,88,88)'[m51];[m51][52]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,89,89)'[m52];[m52][53]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,90,90)'[m53];[m53][54]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,91,91)'[m54];[m54][55]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,93,93)'[m55];[m55][56]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,95,95)'[m56];[m56][57]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,97,97)'[m57];[m57][58]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,98,98)'[m58];[m58][59]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,100,100)'[m59];[m59][60]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,101,101)'[m60];[m60][61]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,103,103)'[m61];[m61][62]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,105,105)'[m62];[m62][63]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,107,107)'[m63];[m63][64]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,109,109)'[m64];[m64][65]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,111,111)'[m65];[m65][66]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,113,113)'[m66];[m66][67]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,115,115)'[m67];[m67][68]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,117,117)'[m68];[m68][69]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,119,119)'[m69];[m69][70]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,120,120)'[m70];[m70][71]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,122,122)'[m71];[m71][72]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,123,123)'[m72];[m72][73]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,125,125)'[m73];[m73][74]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,126,126)'[m74];[m74][75]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,127,127)'[m75];[m75][76]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,129,129)'[m76];[m76][77]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,131,131)'[m77];[m77][78]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,132,132)'[m78];[m78][79]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,134,134)'[m79];[m79][80]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,135,135)'[m80];[m80][81]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,137,137)'[m81];[m81][82]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,139,139)'[m82];[m82][83]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,141,141)'[m83];[m83][84]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,142,142)'[m84];[m84][85]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,144,144)'[m85];[m85][86]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,146,146)'[m86];[m86][87]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,148,148)'[m87];[m87][88]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,150,150)'[m88];[m88][89]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,152,152)'[m89];[m89][90]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,154,154)'[m90];[m90][91]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,155,155)'[m91];[m91][92]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,156,156)'[m92];[m92][93]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,158,158)'[m93];[m93][94]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,159,159)'[m94];[m94][95]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,160,160)'[m95];[m95][96]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,161,161)'[m96];[m96][97]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,162,162)'[m97];[m97][98]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,164,164)'[m98];[m98][99]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,166,166)'[m99];[m99][100]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,168,168)'[m100];[m100][101]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,170,170)'[m101];[m101][102]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,171,171)'[m102];[m102][103]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,172,172)'[m103];[m103][104]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,173,173)'[m104];[m104][105]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,174,174)'[m105];[m105][106]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,175,175)'[m106];[m106][107]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,176,176)'[m107];[m107][108]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,177,177)'[m108];[m108][109]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,178,178)'[m109];[m109][110]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,180,180)'[m110];[m110][111]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,181,181)'[m111];[m111][112]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,183,183)'[m112];[m112][113]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,184,184)'[m113];[m113][114]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,185,185)'[m114];[m114][115]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,186,186)'[m115];[m115][116]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,187,187)'[m116];[m116][117]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,188,188)'[m117];[m117][118]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,292,292)'[m118];[m118][119]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,294,294)'[m119];[m119][120]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,296,296)'[m120];[m120][121]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,298,298)'[m121];[m121][122]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,300,300)'[m122];[m122][123]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,302,302)'[m123];[m123][124]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,303,303)'[m124];[m124][125]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,305,305)'[m125];[m125][126]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,307,307)'[m126];[m126][127]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,309,309)'[m127];[m127][128]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,311,311)'[m128];[m128][129]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,313,313)'[m129];[m129][130]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,315,315)'[m130];[m130][131]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,316,316)'[m131];[m131][132]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,317,317)'[m132];[m132][133]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,319,319)'[m133];[m133][134]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,320,320)'[m134];[m134][135]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,321,321)'[m135];[m135][136]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,322,322)'[m136];[m136][137]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,323,323)'[m137];[m137][138]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,324,324)'[m138];[m138][139]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,325,325)'[m139];[m139][140]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,326,326)'[m140];[m140][141]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,327,327)'[m141];[m141][142]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,328,328)'[m142];[m142][143]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,330,330)'[m143];[m143][144]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,332,332)'[m144];[m144][145]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,333,333)'[m145];[m145][146]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,335,335)'[m146];[m146][147]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,337,337)'[m147];[m147][148]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,338,338)'[m148];[m148][149]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,340,340)'[m149];[m149][150]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,342,342)'[m150];[m150][151]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,343,343)'[m151];[m151][152]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,344,344)'[m152];[m152][153]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,346,346)'[m153];[m153][154]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,347,347)'[m154];[m154][155]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,349,349)'[m155];[m155][156]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,350,350)'[m156];[m156][157]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,352,352)'[m157];[m157][158]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,353,353)'[m158];[m158][159]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,355,355)'[m159];[m159][160]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,357,357)'[m160];[m160][161]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,359,359)'[m161];[m161][162]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,360,360)'[m162];[m162][163]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,361,361)'[m163];[m163][164]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,363,363)'[m164];[m164][165]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,365,365)'[m165];[m165][166]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,367,367)'[m166];[m166][167]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,369,369)'[m167];[m167][168]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,371,371)'[m168];[m168][169]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,373,373)'[m169];[m169][170]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,375,375)'[m170];[m170][171]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,377,377)'[m171];[m171][172]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,379,379)'[m172];[m172][173]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,381,381)'[m173];[m173][174]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,384,384)'[m174];[m174][175]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,386,386)'[m175];[m175][176]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,388,388)'[m176];[m176][177]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,390,390)'[m177];[m177][178]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,391,391)'[m178];[m178][179]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,393,393)'[m179];[m179][180]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,395,395)'[m180];[m180][181]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,397,397)'[m181];[m181][182]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,399,399)'[m182];[m182][183]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,400,400)'[m183];[m183][184]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,401,401)'[m184];[m184][185]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,402,402)'[m185];[m185][186]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,403,403)'[m186];[m186][187]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,404,404)'[m187];[m187][188]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,405,405)'[m188];[m188][189]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,406,406)'[m189];[m189][190]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,407,407)'[m190];[m190][191]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,408,408)'[m191];[m191][192]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,409,409)'[m192];[m192][193]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,410,410)'[m193];[m193][194]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,411,411)'[m194];[m194][195]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,412,412)'[m195];[m195][196]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,414,414)'[m196];[m196][197]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,416,416)'[m197];[m197][198]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,418,418)'[m198];[m198][199]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,418,418)'[m199];[m199][200]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,420,420)'[m200];[m200][201]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,420,420)'[m201];[m201][202]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,422,422)'[m202];[m202][203]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,422,422)'[m203];[m203][204]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,423,423)'[m204];[m204][205]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,423,423)'[m205];[m205][206]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,425,425)'[m206];[m206][207]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,425,425)'[m207];[m207][208]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,427,427)'[m208];[m208][209]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,427,427)'[m209];[m209][210]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,429,429)'[m210];[m210][211]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,429,429)'[m211];[m211][212]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,431,431)'[m212];[m212][213]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,431,431)'[m213];[m213][214]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,433,433)'[m214];[m214][215]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,433,433)'[m215];[m215][216]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,435,435)'[m216];[m216][217]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,435,435)'[m217];[m217][218]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,437,437)'[m218];[m218][219]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,437,437)'[m219];[m219][220]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,438,438)'[m220];[m220][221]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,438,438)'[m221];[m221][222]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,440,440)'[m222];[m222][223]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,440,440)'[m223];[m223][224]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,442,442)'[m224];[m224][225]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,442,442)'[m225];[m225][226]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,443,443)'[m226];[m226][227]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,443,443)'[m227];[m227][228]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,445,445)'[m228];[m228][229]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,445,445)'[m229];[m229][230]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,447,447)'[m230];[m230][231]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,447,447)'[m231];[m231][232]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,449,449)'[m232];[m232][233]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,449,449)'[m233];[m233][234]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,450,450)'[m234];[m234][235]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,450,450)'[m235];[m235][236]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,452,452)'[m236];[m236][237]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,452,452)'[m237];[m237][238]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,454,454)'[m238];[m238][239]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,454,454)'[m239];[m239][240]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,455,455)'[m240];[m240][241]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,455,455)'[m241];[m241][242]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,457,457)'[m242];[m242][243]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,458,458)'[m243];[m243][244]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,459,459)'[m244];[m244][245]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,460,460)'[m245];[m245][246]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,461,461)'[m246];[m246][247]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,463,463)'[m247];[m247][248]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,465,465)'[m248];[m248][249]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,467,467)'[m249];[m249][250]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,468,468)'[m250];[m250][251]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,470,470)'[m251];[m251][252]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,472,472)'[m252];[m252][253]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,474,474)'[m253];[m253][254]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,475,475)'[m254];[m254][255]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,477,477)'[m255];[m255][256]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,478,478)'[m256];[m256][257]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,479,479)'[m257];[m257][258]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,481,481)'[m258];[m258][259]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,482,482)'[m259];[m259][260]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,484,484)'[m260];[m260][261]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,485,485)'[m261];[m261][262]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,486,486)'[m262];[m262][263]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,487,487)'[m263];[m263][264]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,488,488)'[m264];[m264][265]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,490,490)'[m265];[m265][266]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,491,491)'[m266];[m266][267]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,492,492)'[m267];[m267][268]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,493,493)'[m268];[m268][269]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,494,494)'[m269];[m269][270]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,495,495)'[m270];[m270][271]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,496,496)'[m271];[m271][272]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,497,497)'[m272];[m272][273]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,498,498)'[m273];[m273][274]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,499,499)'[m274];[m274][275]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,500,500)'[m275];[m275][276]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,501,501)'[m276];[m276][277]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,502,502)'[m277];[m277][278]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,504,504)'[m278];[m278][279]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,505,505)'[m279];[m279][280]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,507,507)'[m280];[m280][281]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,508,508)'[m281];[m281][282]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,681,681)'[m282];[m282][283]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,682,682)'[m283];[m283][284]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,684,684)'[m284];[m284][285]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,686,686)'[m285];[m285][286]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,688,688)'[m286];[m286][287]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,690,690)'[m287];[m287][288]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,692,692)'[m288];[m288][289]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,694,694)'[m289];[m289][290]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,696,696)'[m290];[m290][291]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,698,698)'[m291];[m291][292]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,700,700)'[m292];[m292][293]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,701,701)'[m293];[m293][294]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,703,703)'[m294];[m294][295]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,704,704)'[m295];[m295][296]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,706,706)'[m296];[m296][297]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,708,708)'[m297];[m297][298]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,710,710)'[m298];[m298][299]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,712,712)'[m299];[m299][300]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,714,714)'[m300];[m300][301]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,716,716)'[m301];[m301][302]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,718,718)'[m302];[m302][303]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,719,719)'[m303];[m303][304]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,721,721)'[m304];[m304][305]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,723,723)'[m305];[m305][306]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,725,725)'[m306];[m306][307]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,727,727)'[m307];[m307][308]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,729,729)'[m308];[m308][309]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,731,731)'[m309];[m309][310]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,733,733)'[m310];[m310][311]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,734,734)'[m311];[m311][312]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,735,735)'[m312];[m312][313]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,736,736)'[m313];[m313][314]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,737,737)'[m314];[m314][315]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,738,738)'[m315];[m315][316]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,739,739)'[m316];[m316][317]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,740,740)'[m317];[m317][318]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,742,742)'[m318];[m318][319]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,743,743)'[m319];[m319][320]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,744,744)'[m320];[m320][321]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,746,746)'[m321];[m321][322]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,748,748)'[m322];[m322][323]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,749,749)'[m323];[m323][324]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,750,750)'[m324];[m324][325]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,751,751)'[m325];[m325][326]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,752,752)'[m326];[m326][327]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,753,753)'[m327];[m327][328]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,754,754)'[m328];[m328][329]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,756,756)'[m329];[m329][330]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,757,757)'[m330];[m330][331]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,758,758)'[m331];[m331][332]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,759,759)'[m332];[m332][333]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,760,760)'[m333];[m333][334]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,761,761)'[m334];[m334][335]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,762,762)'[m335];[m335][336]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,763,763)'[m336];[m336][337]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,764,764)'[m337];[m337][338]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,765,765)'[m338];[m338][339]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,766,766)'[m339];[m339][340]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,768,768)'[m340];[m340][341]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,769,769)'[m341];[m341][342]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,771,771)'[m342];[m342][343]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,773,773)'[m343];[m343][344]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,775,775)'[m344];[m344][345]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,777,777)'[m345];[m345][346]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,779,779)'[m346];[m346][347]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,780,780)'[m347];[m347][348]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,781,781)'[m348];[m348][349]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,783,783)'[m349];[m349][350]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,785,785)'[m350];[m350][351]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,787,787)'[m351];[m351][352]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,789,789)'[m352];[m352][353]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,791,791)'[m353];[m353][354]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,792,792)'[m354];[m354][355]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,794,794)'[m355];[m355][356]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,795,795)'[m356];[m356][357]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,796,796)'[m357];[m357][358]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,798,798)'[m358];[m358][359]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,799,799)'[m359];[m359][360]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,800,800)'[m360];[m360][361]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,801,801)'[m361];[m361][362]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,803,803)'[m362];[m362][363]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,804,804)'[m363];[m363][364]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,806,806)'[m364];[m364][365]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,807,807)'[m365];[m365][366]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,808,808)'[m366];[m366][367]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,809,809)'[m367];[m367][368]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,810,810)'[m368];[m368][369]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,811,811)'[m369];[m369][370]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,812,812)'[m370];[m370][371]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,813,813)'[m371];[m371][372]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,814,814)'[m372];[m372][373]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,815,815)'[m373];[m373][374]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,816,816)'[m374];[m374][375]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,850,850)'[m375];[m375][376]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,852,852)'[m376];[m376][377]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,853,853)'[m377];[m377][378]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,855,855)'[m378];[m378][379]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,857,857)'[m379];[m379][380]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,858,858)'[m380];[m380][381]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,859,859)'[m381];[m381][382]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,861,861)'[m382];[m382][383]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,863,863)'[m383];[m383][384]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,865,865)'[m384];[m384][385]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,867,867)'[m385];[m385][386]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,868,868)'[m386];[m386][387]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,869,869)'[m387];[m387][388]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,870,870)'[m388];[m388][389]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,872,872)'[m389];[m389][390]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,874,874)'[m390];[m390][391]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,876,876)'[m391];[m391][392]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,878,878)'[m392];[m392][393]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,879,879)'[m393];[m393][394]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,881,881)'[m394];[m394][395]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,882,882)'[m395];[m395][396]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,883,883)'[m396];[m396][397]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,885,885)'[m397];[m397][398]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,887,887)'[m398];[m398][399]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,888,888)'[m399];[m399][400]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,890,890)'[m400];[m400][401]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,891,891)'[m401];[m401][402]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,893,893)'[m402];[m402][403]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,894,894)'[m403];[m403][404]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,896,896)'[m404];[m404][405]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,897,897)'[m405];[m405][406]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,898,898)'[m406];[m406][407]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,899,899)'[m407];[m407][408]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,900,900)'[m408];[m408][409]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,901,901)'[m409];[m409][410]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,903,903)'[m410];[m410][411]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,905,905)'[m411];[m411][412]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,907,907)'[m412];[m412][413]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,908,908)'[m413];[m413][414]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,909,909)'[m414];[m414][415]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,910,910)'[m415];[m415][416]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,911,911)'[m416];[m416][417]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,912,912)'[m417];[m417][418]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,913,913)'[m418];[m418][419]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,915,915)'[m419];[m419][420]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,917,917)'[m420];[m420][421]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,919,919)'[m421];[m421][422]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,921,921)'[m422];[m422][423]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,922,922)'[m423];[m423][424]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,924,924)'[m424];[m424][425]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,926,926)'[m425];[m425][426]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,928,928)'[m426];[m426][427]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,930,930)'[m427];[m427][428]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,932,932)'[m428];[m428][429]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,934,934)'[m429];[m429][430]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,935,935)'[m430];[m430][431]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,936,936)'[m431];[m431][432]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,937,937)'[m432];[m432][433]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,938,938)'[m433];[m433][434]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,939,939)'[m434];[m434][435]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,940,940)'[m435];[m435][436]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,941,941)'[m436];[m436][437]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,942,942)'[m437];[m437][438]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,943,943)'[m438];[m438][439]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,944,944)'[m439];[m439][440]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,945,945)'[m440];[m440][441]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,946,946)'[m441];[m441][442]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,947,947)'[m442];[m442][443]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,948,948)'[m443];[m443][444]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,949,949)'[m444];[m444][445]overlay=0:0:enable='between(n,950,950)' -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -y Temp\Videos\5c9b6d5821e7fa9adc1da560.mp4
```

Comment: Wow, that's a line length of 29.705 characters. Maximum, Windows can handle is 8.191 chars / 2047 chars for NT and Win2000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as already answered you in the comment a problem in restriction of length of a line for the Windows console.
use **-filter_complex_script** instead of -filter_complex
you can use it to pass a long filter, but it must be written to a file.

also, to work with ffmpeg for C#, I advise you to use library the NReco.VideoConverter